# LingoVapor package from Vapor 3 to Vapor 4

Tags: swift, package, upgrade, vapor

I am new in swift. Also, there is a project with vapor 3. Now we should upgrade it to the new version.
I have a problem with **LingoVapor** package from "Vapor 3" to "Vapor 4" :

I follow the instructions and change the lines below in my "Package.swift":

```
   dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/wkhtmltopdf.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/lingo-vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/skelpo/CSV.git", from: "1.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "Leaf", package: "leaf"),
                .product(name:  "wkhtmltopdf", package: "wkhtmltopdf"),
                .product(name: "LongoVapor", package: "lingo-vapor"),
                .product(name:  "CSV", package: "CSV")
            ],
```

when I push "Reset Package Caches" I get the following error:

```
Resaving package dependencies
    because lingo-vapor >=3.0.0 depends on vapor 3.0.0..<4.0.0 and root depends on vapor 4.0.0..<5.0.0, lingo-vapor >=3.0.0 is forbidden.
    And because root depends on lingo-vapor 3.0.0..<4.0.0, version solving failed.
```

is there any solution?

Comment: I'd suggest to join Vapor's discord chat to get help

Comment: [vapor-community/Lingo-Vapor](https://github.com/vapor-community/lingo-vapor.git) depends on [miroslavkovac/Lingo](https://github.com/miroslavkovac/Lingo) which has a last commit of [Mar 18, 2018](https://github.com/miroslavkovac/Lingo/commits/master) ... so some effort would be needed to use with Swift5/Vapor4.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the Vapor 4 version of the LingoVapor package and created a PR, https://github.com/vapor-community/Lingo-Vapor/pull/10.

If you want to use it now, please use the forked repo URL:

https://github.com/abhidsm/lingo-vapor.git with version 4.0.0

Please go through the README for setup and use. Thanks.